# Expo React-native-i18n build fails

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I have an expo react native project with the `react-native-i18n` package installed.

When I try to build it I get the following error:

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/build.gradle' line: 25
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-i18n'.
[stderr] >
[stderr] Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or
[stderr] --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 37s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I already changed the build.gradle file's `dependencies` object with `implementation` instead of `compile`, but there seems to be something preventing the build to update to these changes.